# JAVA: Get the ID of database item

Tags: java, persistence

Am am still a beginner in Java and want to do some database programming.

My problem is i created a combo box which I select a value from a table1. When a value is selected together with a jTextField value need to be saved in table2. But I want the ID from table 1 to be saved in table2.

How do I now get the ID of the item in table1 to save it in table2.

```
{  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PTSchemePU");
    CountriesJpaController cjc = new CountriesJpaController(emf);
    RegionsJpaController rjc  = new RegionsJpaController(emf);

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

     List results = em.createNamedQuery("Countries.findAll").getResultList();}
```

If i use the resultlist then it will only give me what is in the toString method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you've named your VOs, but it could be something like this

```
List<CountryVO> results = em.createNamedQuery("Countries.findAll").getResultList();
for (Country c:results){
    Integer id = c.getId();
}
```

Just replaces CountryVO with the name for the class you use for mapping the Country table, a c.getId() for the ID field getter.